# apache spark phoenix connector does not support streamed reading

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-phoenix

We are trying to read the phoenix table data in Apache spark Context. 
The first step, loading the data in memory, we are able to do so.
Now, As we are dealing the real time data in the phoenix tables. We are planning to stream the data that we are reading.

We tried using below mentioned code for that:-

```
  Dataset entityDataSet = spark.readStream()
   .format(dataFormat)
   .option("table", tablename)
   .option("zkUrl", clientUrl)
   .option("driver", driver)
   .load()
   .limit(fetchsize);
```

But when we are executing this in yarn cluster mode or even in local as well , we are getting :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
instantiate [void]: Factory method 'loadIntialPhoenixData' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source 
org.apache.phoenix.spark does not support streamed reading
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiat e(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
```

anybody having idea on this?
any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: I do have the same requirement . Did you able to implement this ?